# Fraction mode using LaTeX

Tags: formatting, fractions

I'm trying to automate my class lessons to gen "standard answer". 
My problem is related to fraction mode.
Let's take the answer:
`0.33333333...`, I would like it appears like `1/3`

Comment: How are you generating your standard answers?

Comment: I'm using a structure to solve linear systems, but for each exercise I need change numbers to new one as a result of manual calculation. Another example is related to solve matrix determinant. I've created a list of exercise with 30 questions.

`$$
\begin{matrix}
1&2\\
3&4
\end{matrix}=1 \cdot 4 - (2 \cdot 3) = -2
$$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! pgf has means to detect such fractions, `/pgf/number format/frac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.33333333}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tks a lot! Schrödinger's cat, you really alive and make me alive with your answer. ;)